# Concern about algebraic integer

Tags: abstract-algebra, free-modules

To be honest, I don't figure out how to attack this problem:

> Let $\alpha$ an algebraic integer i.e. there is a monic polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ s.t. $f(\alpha)=0$.
>
> Let $R:=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$. For some positive integer $m$, prove that $R/mR$ is finite and determine its order.

I'll appreciate any help/hint.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you find an expression for elements of $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ using powers of $\alpha$?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my late reply.

Following your idea: $F[\alpha]=\{a_0+a_1\alpha+\cdots+a_{n-1}\alpha^{n-1}\mid a_j \in \mathbb{Z}\}$. It looks like $\{\alpha^0,\alpha, \alpha^2,...,\alpha^{n-1}\}$ is a basis for $F[\alpha]$. Moreover, $F[\alpha]\cong \mathbb{Z}^n$ under this basis. Thus, given a positive integer $m$, 
$$
R/mR \cong \mathbb{Z}^n/m\mathbb{Z}^n\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}\oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb{Z}}{m \mathbb{Z}\oplus m\mathbb{Z}\oplus\cdots \oplus m \mathbb{Z}} \quad \textrm{ By invariant factor form}. 
$$
Therefore,
$$
\left|R/mR\right|=m^n.
$$
I would like to be more precisely in each step, it's like the sketch of a possible proof. 
Thanks so much for any extra information that you see might be needed.